# Converting ddmmmyyyy to number with vba

Tags: vba, excel, date

I Have a cell that contains a bit of info and included in that is a date in a ddmmmyy format (sort of "16dec 21 hello").
I need to generate an email where at some part of the email the date is included but in number form (i.e. 16122021, so ddmmyyyy).
I tried first extracting the date using the left() function and then try and convert that into a data either by .numbertype = "ddmmyyyy" and cdate function but it doesnt seem to work. Below is my code:

```
'Getting date
Dim expdt As Date
Dim dt As String
dt = Left(Range("A8").Value, 8)
expdt = CDate("dt")
```

[prints 00:00:00]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try,

```
Dim expdt As Date
Dim dt As String

'your sample had a space between Dec and 21
dt = Left(Range("A8").Value2, 2) & "-" & mid(replace(Range("A8").Value2, chr(32), chr(45)), 3, 6)
expdt = datevalue(dt)
debug.print expdt
```

Comment: that seems to work perfectly. Is there any way of getting rid of the / between the date month and year ?

Comment: It's a real date now; you can format it anyway you wish but I would try to keep it as a true date; e.g. store it in a worksheet cell and format the cell.

Answer (score 1):

Or you may have the following two functions on a Standard Module like Module1 and then get the date in ddmmyyyy format as shown in the Test Macro.

```
Function GetDate(str As String) As String
Dim dtStr As String, m As Long
With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
   .Global = False
   .Pattern = "\d{1,2}\s?[a-zA-Z]{3}\s?\d{2}"
    If .Test(str) Then
        dtStr = .Execute(str)(0)
        m = GetMonth(dtStr)
        If m > 0 Then
            GetDate = Left(dtStr, 2) & m & Right(dtStr, 2)
        End If
    End If
End With
End Function

Function GetMonth(str As String) As Long
Dim m
With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
   .Global = False
   .Pattern = "[a-zA-Z]{3}"
    If .Test(str) Then
        m = DateValue(.Execute(str)(0) & "-1-2018")
        If Not IsError(m) Then GetMonth = Month(m)
    End If
End With
End Function
```

And then you can extract the date from a string in desired date format as shown below...

```
Sub Test()
MsgBox GetDate("16dec 21 hello")
'OR
MsgBox GetDate(Range("A8").Value)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting aside the fact you have a typo - you wanted `CDate(dt)` - `CDate` does **not** support the abbreviated month names. So you need to write out the code longhand. This is such a snippet:

```
Public Function fConvertDate(strDate As String) As Date
Dim bytDay As Byte
Dim intYear As Integer
Dim strMonth As String
Dim bytMonth As Byte

bytDay = Val(Left$(strDate, 2))
intYear = CInt(Mid$(strDate, 6, 4))
strMonth = UCase$(Mid$(strDate, 3, 3))

bytMonth = Val(Switch(strMonth = "JAN", "1", strMonth = "FEB", "2", strMonth = "MAR", "3", _
               strMonth = "APR", "4", strMonth = "MAY", "5", strMonth = "JUN", "6", strMonth = "JUL", "7", _
               strMonth = "AUG", "8", strMonth = "SEP", "9", strMonth = "OCT", "10", strMonth = "NOV", "11", _
               strMonth = "DEC", "12"))

fConvertDate = DateSerial(intYear, bytMonth, bytDay)
End Function
```

Code taken from https://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/969310-how-convert-text-ddmmmyyyy-format-date.